# Is it valid in subversion to branch a subfolder?

Tags: svn

I have a subversion project that have a repository and `trunk`, `tags`, `branches` top-level items. For this project, `trunk` contains a folders for a big parts like 'common', 'libs', 'core', 'help', 'install', 'tests' etc. The question: is it valid in subversion to branch `trunk/common` or do i need to always branch entire `trunk`?

I have checked - all seems work fine while branching `trunk/common`, but TortoiseSVN don't show such branches in `revision graph` :(. This leads me to the assumption that it is not correct to branch something over than `trunk`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can branch every directory in SVN but it's a best practice to branch from trunk. The result in tortoise is cause TortoiseSVN assumes branches are made from trunk folder instead of subfolders. The questions is why do you try that an what advantages do you expect from "branching " a sub-folder instead of trunk?

Comment: I want to add experimental feature to project part 'common'. This experimental feature will take some time. So i want to enable over developers to build app either with trunk version of 'common' OR experimental branch version. Branching entire trunk will prevent my team to build trunk app with experimental common (or will require a sync on each sych build).

Comment: If I'm a developer working on the whole project i can simply switch the subfolder (common) to this branch and build the project locally to test if it works. In this case it doesn't matter if the whole trunk has been branched or the subfolder only. If you need to test this feature from time to time you should work with an integration branch which contains the trunk code merged with the code from the branch you have created. On that branch you can do CI or local builds...An other questions is comming up: Which kind of build tool do you use? Does it support this kind of working?Does not look like

Comment: Wow, thanks! Never though it's possible to switch individual folder to trunk branch

Comment: I have a reason to want branching from a subdirectory. I am working on a huge project, with many teams and sub projects. Every developer wants to create feature branches when coding. If they all go to root/branches, then that folder becomes unmanageable, with a lot of branches. Furthermore, it's not obvious which sub-project these branches belong to, as they are at the same level. Solutions for this?

Comment: Using a good naming schema solves that problem to branch at root level....Furthermore if you create so much branches per sub project it might be helpful to think of separating those different subprojects...and separate them on a logical level and let the dependency solutions being done by different tools..