# Creating a branch from a partial tree of trunk in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to introduce branching/merging using our existing (and exclusive) trunk (which is huge). Here's an example:

```
trunk
    folderA
        folderA1
            folderA1a
        folderA2
    folderB
    folderC
    ...
    folderZ
        folderZ1
            folderZ1a
    libraries

branches
```

The goal would be to to have these paths as a branch:

- trunk/folderA/folderA1/folderA1a
- trunk/folderZ/folderZ1/folderZ1a
- trunk/libraries

So far, I've done the following:

1. I did a checkout of trunk using the dept "Immediate children, including folders". This only shows me branches, tags and trunk
2. I updated folderA1a, folderZ1a and libraries trees from trunk to my working copy. Now I have these 3 full trees in my working copy
3. From my working copy, I ran the following command: svn copy trunk branches/mynewbranch
4. I committed my changes

However, when I browse the repository, mynewbranch contains a mirror copy of trunk's structure instead of just the few trees I had updated. Is it even possible to create a branch from a partial tree of trunk?

**Edit #1**

I went into the trunk folder and ran the following command:

```
svn copy . <path_of_branch>
```

If I look at my working copy, the branch only contains what I need. Which is good.

However, when I commit these changes, all the folders that I excluded originally are present when browsing the repository. When I checkout the branch in question, the unwanted folders are also present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at step 3...

```
svn copy . <path_of_branch>
```

Here `.` means your `working copy` will be created as `branch` which is I believe what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your help. Your suggestion partially worked. Please see Edit #1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged tortoisesvn I'm assuming TortoiseSvn is available.

You may find it easier to perform this sort of operation using the [Repository Browser](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html).

It may be worth bearing in mind that it is considered best practice to [branch trunk](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) and not subfolders of trunk. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4024454/397817) has more details. Note that within the repository there is no significant disk usage penalty for branching the entire trunk because of what subversion calls [cheap copying](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html). Also, you can of course checkout just the subfolder needed from the branch if local disk storage or network bandwidth are issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy every element of `trunk` that you want to have in the `branch`.

```
svn copy directori/file1 url:/svn/directori/file1
svn copy ......
```

or from url to url

```
svn copy url:/svn/test/trunk/file1 url:/svn/test/branches/branch01/file1
```

....